# Will my luggage transfer during an 18h layover in Changi?

Tags: luggage, layovers, singapore-airlines, sin

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate question or not, but mine is specifically for Changi airport in Singapore. The airline is Singapore Airlines.

My flight is from DPS->SIN (Flight 939) and will arrive at 2:30 PM.

My next flight departs SIN (Flight 16) at 9:25AM the next day.

Will my luggage be automatically transferred to the next flight on such a long layover, or will I need to pick it up and re-check it ?

I've never had such a long layover before, so I'm quite confused on this process.

The tickets were all bought together and on the same itinerary, so these were not separate purchases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No** you don't need to claim and recheck your bags. For future reference at Changi, if you're flying with SQ on the same ticket they will transfer them for you.

[Here's](https://twitter.com/SingaporeAir/status/671372151702880260) the answer from their Twitter:

> Are both flights booked under the same booking ref? If yes, the
>   baggage will be check through to the final destination.